# Как сделать бота на запросах с помощью node js

Tags: node.js, post, request

Совершенно не понимаю как научиться писать бота на запросах с помощью Node js. К примеру, чтобы авторизовался на сайте.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Хочу научиться писать бота на запросах.